# Get all unnamed groups in a Python match object

Tags: python, regex

I have a number of related regular expressions that use both named and unnamed groups.  I want to plug the unnamed groups as positional arguments to a function chosen using the named group.

For an example, with the pattern `([abc]+)([123]+)(?P<end>[%#])` matching the string `"aaba2321%"`, I want to get a list containing `["aaba", "2321"]`, but **not** `"%"`

I tried the following:

```
match_obj.groups()
```

under the assumption that it wouldn't capture the named groups as there is a separate method, `groupdict`, for getting only the named groups.  Unfortunately, `groups` included named groups.

Then, I decided to write my own generator for it:

```
def get_unnamed_groups(match_obj):
    index = 1
    while True:
        try: yield match_obj.group(index)
        except IndexError: break
        index += 1
```

Unfortunately the named group can also be accessed as a numbered group.  How do I get the numbered groups alone?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do this. Of course you could iterate the groups in the pattern or the start and end indexes of the groups in the match and skip over the ones that are also in named groups if you really need to, but… why do you want this?

Comment: Also, what did you expect that generator to do? What it's actually going to do the same thing as `iter(match_obj.groups())`, because `groups` is just defined as returning a tuple of the same subgroups with the same indices that `group` uses.

Comment: @abarnert I want it because it would be an inconvenient, redundant, and create potential problems when changing things if I required the data that includes the related regular expressions to also include the indices of the unnamed groups.  I guess I could require all groups to be named, and have the names of the unnamed groups be numbers, but that's what unnamed groups are for.

Comment: @abarnert I wasn't sure how match objects work internally.  It makes sense for `group` to use `groups`, but it would also make sense to have an unnamed groups list.

Comment: If you're not sure, just read the documentation. It seems very clear to me, but if it's not clear to you, someone should probably file a documentation bug (because the docs should be clear to everyone, not just one random person…).

Comment: Meanwhile, I wasn't asking why, given that someone has written these patterns that arbitrarily mix named and unnamed groups, you'd want to do this; the question is why you'd write such patterns in the first place. Unnamed groups are for simple cases where accessing the groups by index makes sense; named groups are for cases where there are too many groups, or optional groups, or a pattern that makes it too complicated to see the numbers, etc.; what's the case where they're both useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a somewhat horrible way to do what you're asking for. It involves indexing all matches by their span (start and end indices) and removing the ones that occur in both `groupdict` and `groups`:

```
named = dict()
unnamed = dict()
all = mo.groups()

# Index every named group by its span
for k,v in mo.groupdict().items():
    named[mo.span(k)] = v

# Index every other group by its span, skipping groups with same 
# span as a named group
for i,v in enumerate(all):
    sp = mo.span(i + 1)
    if sp not in named:
        unnamed[sp] = v

print(named)   # {(8, 9): '%'}
print(unnamed) # {(4, 8): '2321', (0, 4): 'aaba'}
```

The reason indexing by span is necessary is because unnamed and named groups can have the same value. The only unique identifier of a group is where it starts and ends, so this code works fine even when you have groups with the same value. Here is a demo: http://ideone.com/9O7Hpb

Another way to do it would be to write a function that transforms a regex following the form shown in your question to one where all formerly unnamed regexes are named with some prefix and a number. You could match against this regex and pick out the groups that have a name starting with the prefix from `groupdict`

Comment: Your first solution, as it seems you are aware, would have problems if named groups and unnamed groups have the same value.  In my case, this wouldn't be a big problem, but I don't really like it.  However, I didn't really think about transforming the regexes, and I probably should look into doing so.  I think I'll select your answer.

Comment: @potato I'm pretty sure it wouldn't have problems if named groups and unnamed groups had the same value. That is the whole point of indexing by span.

Comment: @potato For example, I've modified my demo to add a `%` at the beginning of the string, and a corresponding group to capture it. Now there is an unnamed group that has the same value as the named group, but they are appropriately separated. See http://ideone.com/9O7Hpb

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what your code was doing.  Yeah, apart from some really weird usage like having a group and an unnamed group in the same place it works great, and is simple and readable unless you are me a few minutes ago.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @potato That's probably because there weren't any comments. I've added a couple to hopefully clarify what the code is doing.

Comment: Found a way to safely identify named groups, keeping overlapping non-named groups. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385788/3423324)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean version, using [`re.regex.groupindex`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.regex.groupindex):

> A dictionary mapping any symbolic group names defined by `(?P<id>)` to group numbers.

---

#### TL;DR: Short copy & paste function:

```
def grouplist(match):
    named = match.groupdict()
    ignored_groups = set()
    for name, index in match.re.groupindex.items():
        if name in named:  # check twice, if it is really the named attribute.
            ignored_groups.add(index)
    return [group for i, group in enumerate(match.groups()) if i+1 not in ignored_groups]


m = re.match('([abc]+)([123]+)(?P<end>[%#])', "aaba2321%")

unnamed = grouplist(m)
print(unnamed)
```

#### Full example

With `groupindex` we get the indexes of the named matches, and can exclude them when building our final list of groups, called `unnamed` in the code below:

```
import re

# ===================================================================================
# This are the current matching groups:
# ===================================================================================
regex = re.compile("(((?P<first_name>\w+)) (?P<middle_name>\w+)) (?P<last_name>\w+)") 
#                   |-------------------- #1 ------------------|
#                    |------- #2 -------|
#                     |------ #3 ------|
#                                          |------- #4 -------|
#                                                                |------ #5 ------|
# ===================================================================================
# But we want to have the following groups instead (regex line is identical):
# ===================================================================================
regex = re.compile("(((?P<first_name>\w+)) (?P<middle_name>\w+)) (?P<last_name>\w+)")
#                   |---------------- #1 (#1) -----------------|
#                    |- first_name (#2) -|
#                     |---- #2 (#3) ----|
#                                          |- middle_name (#4)-|
#                                                                | last_name (#5) |

m = regex.match("Pinkamena Diane Pie")
```

This are the values we want to use, for your convenience:

```
assert list(m.groups()) == [
    'Pinkamena Diane',  # group #1
    'Pinkamena',        # group #2 (first_name)
    'Pinkamena',        # group #3
    'Diane',            # group #4 (middle_name)
    'Pie',              # group #5 (last_name)
]

assert dict(m.groupdict()) == {
    'first_name':  'Pinkamena',  # group #2
    'middle_name': 'Diane',      # group #4
    'last_name':   'Pie',        # group #5
}

assert dict(m.re.groupindex) == {
    'first_name':  2,  # Pinkamena
    'middle_name': 4,  # Diane
    'last_name':   5,  # Pie
}
```

Therefore we can now store the indices of those named groups in a `ignored_groups` set, to omit those groups when filling `unnamed` with `m.groups()`:

```
named = m.groupdict()
ignored_groups = set()
for name, index in m.re.groupindex.items():
    if name in named:  # check twice, if it is really the named attribute.
        ignored_groups.add(index)
    # end if
unnamed = [group for i, group in enumerate(m.groups()) if i+1 not in ignored_groups]
# end for

print(unnamed)
print(named)
```

So in the end we get:

```
# unnamed = grouplist(m)
assert unnamed == [
    'Pinkamena Diane',  # group #1 (#1)
    'Pinkamena',        # group #2 (#3)
]

# named = m.groupdict()
assert named == {
    'first_name':  'Pinkamena',  # group #2
    'middle_name': 'Diane',      # group #4
    'last_name':   'Pie',        # group #5
}
```

Try the example yourself: https://ideone.com/pDMjpP